# Backbone Cannot read property 'property' of undefined error in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I've just decided to learn backbone. I'm following a video tutorial. Everything works fine there, but at my end I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Here's my code:

```
    var MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            var markup = this.options.name + this.options.category + this.options.imagepath;
            // I also had some html markup in the string above, of course, but I've striped it because stackoverflow didn't show it in the preview of my post.
            this.$el.html(markup);
            return this;
        }
    });

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "" : "list",
            "menu-items/new" : "itemForm",
            "menu-items/:item" : "itemDetails"
        },

        list: function() {
            $('#app').html('List screen');
        },

        itemDetails: function(item) {
            var view = new MenuItemDetails({ name: item, category: 'Some category', imagepath: 'no-image.jpg' });
            $('#app').html(view.render().el);
        },

        itemForm: function() {
            $('#app').html('New item form');
        }
    });

    var app = new AppRouter();

    $(function() {
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

The "itemDetails" function gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error. Of course, if I don't use the 'name' property in the view, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined". In the video tutorial that I'm following, everything works fine (it uses version 0.9.1 of backbonejs). I use the latest (1.1.0).

Does anybody know why do I get this error?
There isn't anything misspelled, everything is in the right order (exactly as in the video tutorial, where it works). Why does backbone throws me this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backbone views used to automatically copy the constructor options to `this.options` [but no longer](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> **Change Log**
>   **1.1.0 — Oct. 10, 2013**
>
> - Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as `this.options`, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.

So if you're depending on `this.options` being set in your views then you'll have to do it yourself:

```
var MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.options = options;
    },
    //...
});
```

Or better, unpack the options so that you know what your view's interface is:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = _(options).pick('name', 'category', 'imagepath');
}
```

This way you at least have a list of what you're expecting to see in `options`.

Comment: I like the whitelisting of the options. Another answer worth a read:)

Comment: @nikoshr: Yeah, I never like the automatic `this.options` stuff, too much untraceable "how am I supposed to debug this action-at-a-distance stuff in six months?" magic for my tastes.